# Branches and shared dev servers?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

So I am using Subversion as SCM for a classic ASP webapp that I maintain. We use feature branching to handle changes that have dependencies or longer term development.

We use shared web servers for Dev/QA, and this is where my question comes in. The central Dev server is a working copy of trunk, and then when I need to see changes on Dev from a feature branch I merge them to the Dev working copy. So far so good, but am I setting myself up for ungoodness down the road?

For example, today an analyst told me I could "remove" the changes I had made to a feature and then merged to the Dev site for a demo--not because the feature was being killed, just because he didn't need to see it anymore. And I realized I could not easily do that. The changes I merged now just show up as local modifications on the Dev working copy and I can't easily peel them out (I'd have to manually revert changes to the affected files, since a full revert could/would kill changes related to other features).

The more I write about it the more I feel like I've answered my own question. Do I need to change my branching strategy--branch per environment? Or do I need to have a separate "shared Dev" site for each branch (dev.mysite.com:4801, dev.mysite.com:4802)? Or is this pretty much how you handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the feature you want to remove is exactly and entirely contained in one specific revision, on any branch related to your trunk, you should be able to do a reverse merge of that specific revision on the working copy of your trunk branch. Take a look on the options of the ["svn merge"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html) command. According to this page, you should be able to issue a command like this:

svn merge -c -Revision YourDevBranch YourWorkingCopy

This should remove one revision originaly commited to a branch, from your trunk working copy.

However if the issue is related to several features being commited in only one revision, even in the original development branch, then I guess the only choice is to remove the modifications manually.

Comment: OK you're right, I can reverse merge the changes back out. I have never used that type of merge before. I suppose this validates this approach to some degree?